# Check if String contains only letters

Tags: java, string

The idea is to have a String read and to verify that it does not contain any numeric characters. So something like "smith23" would not be acceptable.

Comment: If you write an extension method for strings, the check can be built in.  You could also use one that's already written such as the [Extensions.cs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extensions.cs) NuGet package that makes it as simple as: For example: "abcXYZ".IsAlphabetic() will return True whereas "abc123".IsAlphabetic() will return False.

Answer (score 159):

What do you want? Speed or simplicity? For speed, go for a loop based approach. For simplicity, go for a one liner RegEx based approach.

**Speed**

```
public boolean isAlpha(String name) {
    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) {
        if(!Character.isLetter(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Simplicity**

```
public boolean isAlpha(String name) {
    return name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
}
```

Comment: I might be pendantic here, but "isLetter" is not the same as [a-zA-Z]

Comment: Keep in mind that in Java, a `char[]` will be encoded as UTF-16. This means a multi-character glyph (where both chars are in the surrogate ranges) will fail to be recognized as a letter when examined individually using `Character.isLetter(char)`. (See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#supplementary) Instead, you would need to use a combination of `String.codePointAt()` and `Character.isLetter(int)`. Of course, if you know *for sure* that the characters in your string are in the ASCII or extended single-char-encoded ranges, then the above answer will work.

Comment: Lambda approach would be even simpler.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky requires API 24 or above.

Comment: @MaihanNijat use RetroLambda

Answer (score 88):

Java 8 lambda expressions. Both fast and simple.

```
boolean allLetters = someString.chars().allMatch(Character::isLetter);
```

Comment: Note that allMatch requires API level 24

Comment: @capt.swag this question is about Java generally, I believe you are probably referring to Android when you say "API level 24"

Answer (score 40):

Or if you are using Apache Commons, [[StringUtils.isAlpha()]](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

Answer (score 13):

First import Pattern :

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Then use this simple code:

```
String s = "smith23";
if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+",s)) { 
  // Do something
  System.out.println("Yes, string contains letters only");
}else{
  System.out.println("Nope, Other characters detected");    
}
```

This will output:

> Nope, Other characters detected

Answer (score 6):

I used this regex expression `(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*")`. With `if not` statement it will avoid all expressions that have a letter before, at the end or between any type of other character.

```
String strWithLetters = "123AZ456";
if(! Pattern.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*", str1))
 return true;
else return false
```

Comment: the `.*` at the start and end of it is not correct. As they can be any length and include digits, `123smith123` would be a valid name. Something like ``^[a-zA-Z]+$` would work though, if it's only the single word in the string.

Comment: I guess I gave a wrong answer. You are right.
My code checks if the String does not have any letter.

Answer (score 5):

A **quick** way to do it is by:

```
public boolean isStringAlpha(String aString) {
    int charCount = 0;
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    if (aString.length() == 0) {
        return false; //zero length string ain't alpha
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length(); j++) {
            if (aString.substring(i, i + 1).equals(alphabet.substring(j, j + 1))
                    || aString.substring(i, i + 1).equals(alphabet.substring(j, j + 1).toLowerCase())) {
                charCount++;
            }
        }

        if (charCount != (i + 1)) {
            System.out.println("\n**Invalid input! Enter alpha values**\n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Because you don't have to run the whole `aString` to check if it isn't an **alpha String**.

Comment: Works only for english

Answer (score 4):

```
private boolean isOnlyLetters(String s){
    char c=' ';
    boolean isGood=false, safe=isGood;
    int failCount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        c = s.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isLetter(c))
            isGood=true;
        else{
            isGood=false;
            failCount+=1;
        }
    }
    if(failCount==0 && s.length()>0)
        safe=true;
    else
        safe=false;
    return safe;
}
```

I know it's a bit crowded. I was using it with my program and felt the desire to share it with people. It can tell if any character in a string is not a letter or not. Use it if you want something easy to clarify and look back on.

Answer (score 4):

Faster way is below. Considering letters are only a-z,A-Z.

```
public static void main( String[] args ){ 
        System.out.println(bestWay("azAZpratiyushkumarsinghjdnfkjsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"));
        System.out.println(isAlpha("azAZpratiyushkumarsinghjdnfkjsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"));

        System.out.println(bestWay("azAZpratiyushkumarsinghjdnfkjsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"));
        System.out.println(isAlpha("azAZpratiyushkumarsinghjdnfkjsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"));
    }

    public static boolean bettertWay(String name) {
        char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
        long startTimeOne = System.nanoTime();
        for(char c : chars){
            if(!(c>=65 && c<=90)&&!(c>=97 && c<=122) ){
                System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - startTimeOne);
                    return false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - startTimeOne);
        return true;
    }


    public static boolean isAlpha(String name) {
        char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
        long startTimeOne = System.nanoTime();
        for (char c : chars) {
            if(!Character.isLetter(c)) {
                System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - startTimeOne);
                return false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - startTimeOne);
        return true;
    }
```

Runtime is calculated in nano seconds. It may vary system to system.

```
5748//bettertWay without numbers
true
89493 //isAlpha without  numbers
true
3284 //bettertWay with numbers
false
22989 //isAlpha with numbers
false
```

Answer (score 4):

Check this,i guess this is help you because it's work in my project so once you check this code

```
if(! Pattern.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*[a-zA-Z]", str1))
 {
   String not contain only character;
 }
else 
{
  String contain only character;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using regular expressions: [String.matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3):

```
        String expression = "^[a-zA-Z]*$";
        CharSequence inputStr = str;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
        if(matcher.matches())
        {
              //if pattern matches 
        }
        else
        {
             //if pattern does not matches
        }
```

Comment: That's a more complicated version of the "Simplicity" thing @adarshr posted three years ago?

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isAlpha(String name)
{
    String s=name.toLowerCase();
    for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if((s.charAt(i)>='a' && s.charAt(i)<='z'))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This does only check the first char! So `A12341` would return `true`. -1

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih, yes you were right. I have edited it. Please check now

Comment: I removed my downvote. This answer is correct now, but can be easily be enhanced by removing the `continue` block. 
`public boolean isAlpha(String name)
        {
            String s = name.toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            {
                if ((s.charAt(i) < 'a' || s.charAt(i) > 'z'))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }`

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Feels as if our need is to find whether the character are only alphabets.
Here's how you can solve it-

```
Character.isAlphabetic(c)
```

helps to check if the characters of the string are alphabets or not.
where c is

```
char c = s.charAt(elementIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are many ways to skin this cat, I prefer to wrap such code into reusable extension methods that make it trivial to do going forward.  When using extension methods, you can also avoid RegEx as it is slower than a direct character check.  I like using the extensions in the Extensions.cs NuGet package.  It makes this check as simple as:

1. Add the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extensions.cs package to your project.
2. Add "`using Extensions;`" to the top of your code.
3. `"smith23".IsAlphabetic()` will return False whereas `"john smith".IsAlphabetic()` will return True.  By default the `.IsAlphabetic()` method ignores spaces, but it can also be overridden such that `"john smith".IsAlphabetic(false)` will return False since the space is not considered part of the alphabet.
4. Every other check in the rest of the code is simply `MyString.IsAlphabetic()`.

Answer (score 0):

To allow only ASCII letters, the character class `\p{Alpha}` can be used. (This is equivalent to `[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]` or `[a-zA-Z]`.)

```
boolean allLettersASCII = str.matches("\\p{Alpha}*");
```

For allowing all Unicode letters, use the character class `\p{L}` (or equivalently, `\p{IsL}`).

```
boolean allLettersUnicode = str.matches("\\p{L}*");
```

See the [`Pattern` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy of way of checking a string whether all its digit is letter or not.

```
public static boolean isStringLetter(String input) {

    boolean b = false;
    for (int id = 0; id < input.length(); id++) {
        if ('a' <= input.charAt(id) && input.charAt(id) <= 'z') {
            b = true;
        } else if ('A' <= input.charAt(id) && input.charAt(id) <= 'Z') {
            b = true;
        } else {
            b = false;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

I hope it could help anyone who is looking for such method.

Answer (score -1):

Use StringUtils.isAlpha() method and it will make your life simple.

Comment: this is a copy of another solution to the question. Please consider updating it to do something different.