# how to find String contain any alphabetic or numeric characters using java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple way to determine if string is only characters, or to check if string contains any numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/simple-way-to-determine-if-string-is-only-characters-or-to-check-if-string-conta)

I want to find if a given String has any alphabetic or numeric characters. How would I do this using java?

Thanks

Comment: "find" in what? Please provide a more thorough explanation of what you want to achieve and/or an example (if possible).

Comment: Did you try searching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/simple-way-to-determine-if-string-is-only-characters-or-to-check-if-string-conta

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense as written, but nevertheless... StackOverflow can be cruel to people whose native language is not English (5 downvotes?!?).  Did you mean to ask, "How can I determine whether a String represents a number"?  If so, then you can you can use either regular expressions or the Apache StringUtils library as has been suggested.  You may also see some code examples where people use "Double.parseDouble()" and try to catch a NumberFormatException... but it's really not good practice to use try-catch blocks to drive logic in that manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String s = "%$a*";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find())
  System.out.println("The string \"" + s + "\" contains alphanumerical characters.");
```

Comment: This only handles ASCII alphabetical characters.

Comment: +1 for @sudocode: *especially* if the OP is not a native english speaker, chances are he needs to support non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @sudocode and @Joachim Sauer I agree, but for my defense, I had not much to work with. My answer is correct as long as the question remains that vague.

Comment: @Oltarus: I agree with the "not much to work with" part. *But* `ä`, `ö` and `ß` are certainly alphabetic, just as `ě`, `ë` and `Ç`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two convenience methods in the `Character` class that would help you

- [`isLetter(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29)
- [`isDigit(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29)

All that's required is transforming a `String` to a character array, and then stepping through the array.