# Check string for a given alphabet

Tags: java, string, performance

I need to check if a string (word, no whitespaces) has any letters of a given alphabet.

```
String A: apple
String B: bed
Alphabet: a b c d e f
```

I want to compare efficiently the string with the alphabet.
What I want is to check if String consists of the letters in Alphabet.
For now I have my alphabet in an ArrayList and in a for loop
I check if String contains the letter of the arraylist and if true then exit, else
continue with the next letter. 
The example above for String A will return false because p and l are not part of the alphabet. But it will return true for B.

Can this be done more efficiently?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Regex: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Just for clarification, for you example, do you expect `true` (because the text contains a `a` which is part of the alphabet) or `false` (because the text contains an `p` which is not part of the alphabet)?

Comment: Good question. Let me update my question.

Comment: This is a semi-dupe of [Check if String contains only letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/check-if-string-contains-only-letters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the "alphabet" into a regex then use [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29). Not sure what you're after exactly, but I'm pretty sure it's one of there two options:

To check that the word has *at least one* of the letters in the alphabet:

```
if (str.matches(".*[abcdef].*"))
```

To check if the word consists *only* of the letters of the alphabet:

```
if (str.matches("[abcdef]+"))
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake but could you check my question again? It was wrong. Now it explains what I want. (Already upvoted you though)

Comment: Thank you for both of the solutions. When I check them I'll accept your answer.

Comment: You could even use ranges `"[a-f]+"`.

Comment: No, that's not an option. The characters will be utf-8 material.

Comment: @JoopEggen yes, however the example given was a poor example - I think it was supposed to be arbitrary letters.

Comment: Is regex faster than doing it in a couple of loops?

Comment: @Averroes My guess is that regex would probably be faster, but even if not, when programming one should do the simplest thing that works. If there's a performance problem, discover that in testing to prove where the problem is and how big it is first. Only then should you attempt optimization to replace simple code with complicated code that's faster.

Comment: Yes, I agree but I think the question was a bit misleading then because the OP is asking for a "more efficiently" way to do it so I thought he was asking for a more time efficiently. I ran a few benchmarks and the regex was slower than the loops.

Answer (score 0):

check this this will give you an idea how to do this
check this..http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm