# Stuck on how to make string character input only

Tags: java

for the last few hours i've been trying to get this code to only allow character input, as its for accepting names..
I have been following the same type of method i used to allow only integers, but with no luck.
any advice would be great,
Here is my code

```
            String name;
            System.out.println("Enter student's name: ");
            name = in.nextLine();
            while (!in.nextLine().matches("[a-zA-Z]"));
            {   
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid name!: ");
                in.next();
                }
            name = in.nextLine();
```

Comment: You might like checking [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/check-if-string-contains-only-letters)

Comment: You consume your valid name in the checking process anyway...

Comment: Are you trying to get first name, mi, and last name, is that what the single char check is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex checks if the line matches **exactly one** [a-zA-Z] character. You probably want to check at least one: `[a-zA-Z]+`

Bear in mind that the way you are checking, you won't get what you have checked in the variable name, as you are consuming it in your checking. Can I propose an alternative:

```
System.out.println("Enter student's name: ");
String name = in.nextLine();
while(!name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid name!");
    name = in.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: How could i get this to allow spaces?

Comment: @user3050340 Just add a space to the regex: `[a-zA-Z ]+` This essentially means any character between the brackets, at least once.

Comment: Ah i see, i understand. Thanks for your help. My programme is up and running now :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with regex, personally, so I would just go with a method that takes a string and determines whether it is only comprised of the alphabets.

[EDIT] Shame on me, the method for testing if a character is a letter is static. Thanks to dansalmo for reminding me.

```
public static boolean isAlphabetic(String s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Use `if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) return false`.  Otherwise Static Error: No method in Character with name 'isLetter' matches this invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the value of the variable name?
While you assign the input to name , you seem to read the next line for regex check.
Remove the in.next too and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Bucco's solution but iterating over a char array:

```
public static boolean isAlphabetic(String s) {
    for(char c : s.toCharArray())
        if (!Character.isLetter(c)) return false;
    return true;
}
```