# How to handle reading from files where lines aren't well-formed

Tags: java, arrays, token, readline

I have a directory with several text files in it, each of which contains a line of text that is delimited by commas.  I am expecting to find 4 tokens as I read from each file while creating a String array.  So, a normal line in the text file would be like this:

```
cat,dog,876358293472,884459654596
```

But I want to account for files that are not formed as I expect.  Or if the file is empty.  For instance, a file might have only this:

```
cat,dog,
```

or

```
cat,0000000000000
```

I have some code to handle the token length but am not sure how to account for cases where the file isn't formatted like I expect.  Here's what I have so far:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        try {
            String [] tokens = line.trim().split(",");
            if (tokens.length != 4) {
                return null;
                }
```

Are there other checks I should do in addition to 'token.length'?

Comment: That will depend on your requirements. There's no "universal rule" to check if "a line is formatted like I expect". You'll have to answer that to yourself: what do you expect?  :- )

Comment: Ah yes, I do expect the second two tokens to be numbers.

Comment: So you want `tokens[0]` and `tokens[1]` to have alpha characters, and `tokens[2]` and `tokens[3]` to have numeric ones? You might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/check-if-string-contains-only-letters) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `split(",",-1)`, to prevent empty fields from merging:

```
"a,b,c,".split(",") --> ["a", "b", "c"]

"a,b,c,".split(",",-1) --> ["a", "b", "c", ""]
```

If all you care about is getting 4 strings, then the test is fine.