# Validating a string scanner

Tags: java, string, while-loop

I am creating an "add customer" method and I want to validate the "add forename" scanner so that only a string can be entered and if the user enters an int etc it will throw up an error, below is the code I have got so far.
I have used "Harry" as an example, the concept seems to be working but obviously not every customer is going to be called Harry. Any help would be welcome!

```
boolean validInput12 = false;
            String userOption13 = "";
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Customer Forename");
                if (sc2.hasNext()) {    
                    userOption13 = sc2.next();
                    if (userOption13.matches("Harry")) {
                        validInput12 = true;
                    sc2.nextLine();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Input invalid: Please select a valid customer forename");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.print("Input invalid: Please enter a valid name \n");
                sc2.nextLine();
            }
        } while (!validInput12);
```

Comment: Look for some regex expression.

Comment: You will need to change 2 things. 1. Use `nextLine()` all the time and don't use `next()`. 2. use `yourString.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")` to ensure only characters are entered. This will ensure that your code works when people enter `Ron` or `Hermoine` :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if String contains only letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/check-if-string-contains-only-letters)

Comment: You're a star thank you! This seemed to work.

Comment: @MelissaWarrington - You will have to change your code a little. use `hasNextLine()` instead of next

Comment: Got it! if I wanted to add backslashes as well would it simply be ("[a-zA-Z /]+")  ? @VinodMadyalkar

Comment: @MelissaWarrington - Yes, I think you'll probably need spaces as well?

Comment: Do you know how to do this for a double, such a currency? 5.00?