# How to check if user entered a string that only contains letters?

Tags: java

How can I check if the user entered a valid string? For example if the user entered "cat" then it would valid, but if the user entered "cat'12ed" then it would be invalid because it should include only letters.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any code to post?

Comment: [Java Regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) can do this for you easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can check to see if the String is alpha, or alphanumeric using pattern matching, like so:

```
public boolean validate(String myString) {
    if ( myString == null) return false;
    return myString.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+");
}
```

There is also commons `StringUtils` which has an alphanumeric method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your String to be valid if it has only letters you have to use patterns for example:

```
if(Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", yourString)) {
//ok it's valid
} else {
//no, it'n not valid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try regex - this should work for you

```
System.out.println("cat".matches("[a-zA-Z]+"));

System.out.println("cat'12ed".matches("[a-zA-Z]+"));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Apache Commons StringUtils: [StringUtils.isAlpha()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

This question is a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/check-if-string-contains-only-letters).