# JavaFX String Validation

Tags: java, string, function, validation, javafx

I'm trying to validate a text field using IF statements.

When I use:

```
if(fname.getText().matches("[a-z]") || fname.getText().matches("[A-Z]")) {
                    grid1.getChildren().remove(labelstar1);                 
                }
```

It only matches one character. How do I make it validate so it matches with a string of characters with no specific length?

Any help/thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: use .matches("[a-zA-Z]+")

Comment: This would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/check-if-string-contains-only-letters

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: cool then! I have posted that in answer section too, which you may accept so that it helps others in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you!

```
if(fname.getText().matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
                    grid1.getChildren().remove(labelstar1);                 
}
```

Similar thing has already been answered here
[Check if String contains only letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/check-if-string-contains-only-letters)