# Validate Input - String

Tags: java, string, validation

I am trying to validate input from a textfield so that it only contains characters from a-z. I am using the following method to validate if the input is an int:

```
//VALIDATE IF INPUT IS NUMERIC.
public static boolean isInt(JFXTextField txtUserInput, String userInput) {
    try {
        int intValidation = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
        txtUserInput.setStyle("-fx-border-color: ; -fx-border-width: 0px ;");
        return true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException exception) {
        showErrorMsg("Invalid Input:", "Please enter a numeric-only value");
        txtUserInput.setStyle("-fx-border-color: RED; -fx-border-width: 1px ;");
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this using a String? I know there is a different way of doing this using an if statement but I was wondering if I can catch an exception like in the example above.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if String contains only letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/check-if-string-contains-only-letters)

Comment: You can throw your own exception. Using an if statement is more performant than try catch

Answer (score 1):

You can use `matches` with regex so if you want to check your input is an int or not you can use:

```
String userInput = ...;
if(userInput.matches("\\d+")){
    System.out.println("correct");
}else{
    System.out.println("Not correct");
}
```

---

If you want to check if the input contain only alphabetic, you can use :

```
if(userInput.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
    System.out.println("correct");
}else{
    System.out.println("Not correct");
}
```

---

If you want to check if your input contains alphanumeric you can use :

```
if(userInput.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")){
    System.out.println("correct");
}else{
    System.out.println("Not correct");
}
```

Comment: The integers was only an example

Comment: i don't know @TimBiegeleisen this is sad in the first second dv

Comment: what did you mean @cricket_007 ?

Comment: I understand that the OP want to validate if an input is an Integer of not @cricket_007 if i'm wrong explain to me !

Comment: @YCF_L actually, the OP is contradicting. First says "*contains characters from a-z*" and then "*method to validate if the input is an int*". Not your fault. You're correct in your interpretation of it.

Comment: @cricket_007 what about my solution now?

Comment: The question still only asks for a-z

Comment: @cricket_007 i do that just for you :) to prove that the question was not clear, for that my first answer was like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

```
if (!userInput.matches("[a-z]+"))
    // Has characters other than a-z
```

If you want to allow uppercase too:

```
if (!userInput.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
    // Has characters other than a-z or A-Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
if (!userInput.matches(".*[^a-z].*")) { 
    // Do something
}
```

Alternative solution to @Bohemian♦ to allow uppercase:

```
if (!userInput.toLowerCase().matches(".*[^a-z].*")) { 
    // Do something
}
```

A similar method, according to your source:

```
public static boolean containsAZ(JFXTextField txtUserInput) {
        if (!txtUserInput.getText().toLowerCase().matches(".*[^a-z].*"))
            return true;
        else
            System.err.println("Input is not containing chars between A-Z");

        return false;
}
```

---

There your question is, if it's possible to throw/catch an exception, you could do the following:

```
public static boolean containsAZ(JFXTextField txtUserInput) {
        try {
            if (!txtUserInput.toLowerCase().matches(".*[^a-z].*")) {
                return true;
            } else
                throw new MyException("Something happened");
        } catch (MyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Considering that you'll need a class:

```
class MyException extends Exception {

    public MyException(String e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

---

An abstract solution would be:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
        // special exception code goes here
}
```

Throw it as:

```
 throw new MyException ("Something happened")
```

Catch as:

```
catch (MyException e)
{
   // Do something
}
```

For more info, [check this for regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).