# How to only allow the user to enter an input of a-z and using an if statement to prompt the correct input

Tags: java

I need to only allow a user to enter a character from the a-z range. I was thinking of using an if statement but its not working out for me.

```
        System.out.println("Please enter letters of the alphabet");
        String input1 = scnObj.nextLine();
        if (input1 != a-z) {
        System.out.println("Please try again.");
        }  
        else 
        {
        System.out.println("Correct.");
        }
```

Comment: Must it be a single character or can the user enter a word?

Comment: @Spiderman it can be a single character, I also should of included that capital letters would be allowed also!

Comment: @Nexus_Valentine Can be or must be?

Comment: @Ivar The entered input from the user must be only a letter or letters from the alphabet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if String contains only letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/check-if-string-contains-only-letters)

Comment: @Ivar That method does not prompt the user to enter the correct format. That is why I would like to us the if statement.

Comment: @Nexus_Valentine You already prompt the user. All you need to do is use one of the methods mentioned there, and check if `input1` matches it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regexp. Your case is simple and something like this:

```
if(!Pattern.compile("[a-z]*").matcher(line).matches()){
   System.out.println("Please try again.");
}
```

If you want include also Uppercase, modfy if condition like this:

```
if(!Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]*").matcher(line).matches()){
   System.out.println("Please try again.");
}
```

If space are allowed:

```
if(!Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z\\s]*").matcher(line).matches()){
   System.out.println("Please try again.");
}
```

In any case and for more complex cases please read [the java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Thanks @Renato Do I have to import anything?

Comment: Sure: you must have `import java.util.regex.Matcher; `  and `import java.util.regex.Pattern;` but these are part of Java SE

Comment: so there is 3 imports with the scanner class as well? Is that right?

Comment: If you want read the input string from the standard input or from a file, yes, you can use Scanner and then you have to add the third import

Comment: Also I had to replace .matcher(line) with                     .matcher (input1). Other then that your solution works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression, but a simpler solution might be to take advantage of the fact that the characters in `a` - `z` are a in a linear progression within the character set tables and do something like...

```
    String input1 = scnObj.nextLine();
    if (!input1.trim().isEmpty()) {
        char inputChar = input1.charAt(0);
        if (inputChar >= 'a' && inputChar <= 'z') {
            // Everything is good
        } else {
            // Everything is bad
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect time for a regex implementation. If you have never heard regex I recommend checking out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sa-TUpSx1JA). Essentially it is used to match patterns within a string. For java you could simply check whether each character is a lower case letter with:

```
System.out.println("Please enter letters of the alphabet");
String input1 = scnObj.nextLine();
if (!input1.matches("[a-z]*") {
    System.out.println("Please try again.");
}  else  {
    System.out.println("Correct.");
}
```

However it might have to add a little more if you want to allow for spaces/hyphens. Good luck!