# java how to split a mixed language string

Tags: java, android

I have a string. (the input string is always an English sentence and its translation in another Lang. but in one line, without limiter.)

```
String str = "2019雨降るしですね。It rains 2019.";
```

how can I separate it into two?

```
2019雨降るしですね。

It rains 2019.
```

I tried this, but failed..

```
                String aString = "2019/1/1，なにげない日々。2019/1/1 is a simple day.";
                Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([\\p{InHiragana}]+)"); 
                Matcher m = pat.matcher(aString);
                System.out.println(m.find()); // true
                String firstHour = m.group(0);
                System.out.println(firstHour);
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please? And do you have a delimiter?

Comment: no delimiter. the problem is hard.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`\W` can be an option for characters not in `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` set.

A quick solution for your first case: `(\\d{4})(\\W+)(\\s*)(.*)`

Comment: is there a more generic way. the input is an English sentence and its translation in another Lang. but in one line. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you instead try and improve the format you are receiving the data in, as this problem cannot be solved with 100% accuracy. That being said, here's one approach that will work for most cases:

1. Split string into words (e.g. `.split(" ")`)
2. For first item in array:

   1. [Check if word is all English letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/check-if-string-contains-only-letters)  (if it's all numbers, move to next word).
   2. Store this value.
3. For every other item in array:

   1. Check if word is all english letters.
   2. If it is, and the previous word was non-english letters, you have your breakpoint.
4. [Merge back together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java) the first X words and last X words on either side of the breakpoint.

You'll now have 2 strings. One with your non-English string, one with your English string. You'll have to do a lot of testing, and likely improve the approach towards numbers (split on numbers using regex?), but this is a start.