# OneTimePad Encryption

Tags: java

I'm working on encrypted text using ascii value and I have this code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class OneTimePad{
   public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner _user_ = new Scanner(System.in);  //Scanner Obj
    
        System.out.print(" Enter your Message : ");
        String Message = _user_.next();
        System.out.print(" Enter your Key : ");
        String Key = _user_.next();
        
        char Fnal;
        int Total;

         for(int l = 0 , m = 0; (l < Message.length() && m < Key.length()); l++,m++){   
            Total = (int)Message.charAt(l) + (int)Key.charAt(m);
           
            if((Total >=65 && Total <= 90) || (Total >= 97 && Total <=122 )){
                    System.out.print("Case 1");
                    Fnal = (char)Total;
                    System.out.print(Fnal);
            }else{
                System.out.print("Case 2");
                int a    = Total % 26;
                Fnal = (char)a;
                System.out.print(Fnal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

> **Enter your Message :** hello
>
> **Enter your Key :** hihih

Why only this two lines are printed on console? I don't see any error.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's my new code:

```
for(int l = 0 , m = 0; (l < Message.length() && m < Key.length()); l++,m++) {   
  Total = (int)Message.charAt(l) + (int)Key.charAt(m);
  //char s = Message.charAt(l);
  char dos = Message.charAt(l);
  String comp = String.valueOf(dos);

  if (comp.contains("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")){
    if(Total >=65 && Total <= 90){
      Fnal = (char)Total;
      System.out.print(Fnal);
    }else{
       int a    = Total % 26 + 65 ;
       Fnal = (char)a;
       System.out.print(Fnal);
    }
  }
}
```

Why it didn't Working?

Comment: It is because the results of addition is out-of-range of `(Total >=65 && Total <= 90) || (Total >= 97 && Total <=122 )` and therefore only control characters (character code less than 32) are printed. What is your desired behavior?

Comment: I am printing  encrypted text using ascii value , i can resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every integer has a visible character associated with it. You can use this simple method to print a list of integer and the relative char:

```
public static void printChars(){
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        System.out.println(i+" -> "+(char)i);
    }//for
}//printChars
```

So, why you don't see any output? Lets try with an example.

> **Enter your Message:** a
>
> **Enter your Key:** s

- `(int)Message.charAt(l)` will be *97*;
- `(int)Key.charAt(m)` will be
  *115*;
- Finally, `Total = (int)Message.charAt(l) + (int)Key.charAt(m)` will be *212*.

The two conditions `Total >=65 && Total <= 90` and `Total >= 97 && Total <=122` are **not** verified, so we have to see what happens in the "else" block.

- `int a = Total % 26` will be *4*

As you can see by using the previous method *printChars()*, no visible character is associated with the number 4, therefore nothing is shown as output.

---

**Tip:** try to use some numeric input, for example

> **Enter your Message:** 0
>
> **Enter your Key:** 3

- `Total` will be `48+51=99`

The conditions are verified, so we have to go in the "if" block. The output will be `(int)99`, so we will see:

> **c**

---

**UPDATE**

In your new code, first of all you have to define *Total* and *Fnal* as **int**. For example:

> **int** Total = (int)Message.charAt(l) + (int)Key.charAt(m);

The main error is the use of [contains(...)](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_contains.asp).

If you write `comp.contains("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")`, you say that the string must have `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` as a substring (and not *"A or B or C ..."*).

Probably you need a **Pattern**, and you can read a similar question here: [Check if String contains only letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/check-if-string-contains-only-letters)

Comment: Thanks a lot , it is very usefull for me.

Comment: @sketchhacker Glad to have been helpful! If my answer has solved your problem, you can select it as "accepted" by clicking on the "v" button to the left of my answer. :D

Comment: Hey , please check again  , i edited my code , and please resolve my code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Again

Comment: Hey ,, i posted a question please tell me that the logic is right or not.

Comment: It's work's  fine , but my friend is telling that the logic is wrong ,

Comment: What is the logic you should follow? Is there a trace for this homework? The code reflects your comments, so if the logic is that the code is right.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Onetimepad{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    
    Scanner _user_ = new Scanner(System.in);    // A Scanner Obj for to take input from user.
                            // System.in is to writing something on console
    
       // Take Message and key from user
    
    System.out.print(" Enter Message : ");
    String Message = _user_.next();

    System.out.print(" Enter Key ");
    String Key = _user_.next();

    // Converting each String latter into Character . And finding that latter's ascii value and 
    // And add that value to key's ascii value , and if it is greater than max than % 26.

    if (Message.length() == Key.length())
      { 
    for(int i = 0 , j = 0 ; i < Message.length() && j < Key.length() ; i++,j++)
    {
        char chmsg = Message.charAt(i);      // "V" = 'V'    
        char chkey = Key.charAt(j);    // "D" = 'D' 
        
        int chpr = (int)chmsg + (int)chkey; 
        
        if(chpr >= 65 && chpr <= 90)
        {
                 System.out.print((char)chpr);
        }
        else
        {
             chpr = chpr % 26+ 65;
             System.out.print((char)chpr);
        }
    } 
    
      }
    else
    {
      System.out.print(" Length of Message and Key is not same : ");
    }

}
} 


// What it is write code and the logic is right.
//Please Tell, It's a OneTimePad Encryption.
```